# Restoring previous Windows 7 data after a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning, windows, mount, windows-7

Sorry if this has been asked before. Hope you'll bear with Linux newbie....

Fairly new to Ubuntu. Installed it on my desktop previously running win7. I backed up my data in the C partition and thought that would be sufficient if I did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 it would not touch the other partitions. Unfortunately that's not the case I guess. I guess I chose the wrong option while installing Ubuntu (erase hard disk or something like that). I thought it'd only format the c drive. Now I can't see any other mounted or unmounted partitions in file manager. The command 'sudo blkid' doesn't list any partitions with ntfs or fat file systems either. So just wanted to ask is there any way to get my data on other partitions back?

Comment: Stop using this drive as primary and use tools like EaseUS Data Recovery. It would be better to save the data on another system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Danatela. The link you provided helps a lot. Thank you again.